# Questions about ddosing?

Tags: ddos

Suppose a website is hit by a 500 Mbps DDos, and then the DDos stops for a second or so; does the website recuperate?

Comment: If the website does rate-limiting, it would be able to recover quite quickly.

Comment: @QuestionOverflow is binary address rate limiting in nginx sufficient?

Comment: @r3wt, to be really effective, rate-limiting must occur at the firewall level, not at the web server.

Answer (score 3):

It depends.

A DoS attack, stereotypically, is an excessive flood of network packets that causes a system to become unavailable or unusable to legitimate users. They are, in essence, exhaustion attacks. Not every DoS aims to exhaust the same *resource* - a system has many resource types and a DoS condition may be caused by exhausting one or more.

The most prolific type of DoS, at least in terms of media representation, is a massive flood of network traffic designed to starve the target system's connection to the internet. These can be achieved in a number of ways, but in general it's just about blocking the incoming pipe with too much data. If this flood stops for a few seconds, the server *may* recover, depending on the configuration of the network.

There are a few cases where it might not:

- A system in the network path (either the target itself, a load balancer, firewall, router, etc.) runs out of space in its state table and fails.
- A system in the network path exhausts its RAM, CPU, disk, or overheats, causing an outage.
- A system in the network path caches the incoming traffic into a queue, causing the DoS to continue internally after the external attack stops.

Of course, this assumes that the attack is purely aimed at "clogging the pipes". Many other DoS conditions are possible:

- CPU / memory exhaustion due to expensive requests.
- Disk exhaustion (either space or IO) through excessive logs or database writes.
- On limited hosting, exhausting the periodical bandwidth limit.
- Triggering a crash in the server software stack (e.g. null pointer dereference)

These may take time or manual intervention to recover.

Answer (score 0):

What DDOS does is that it eats up the bandwidth and also makes the server to process alot of junk requests, Which causes the server to get very slow or unable to perform services. so lets say 500mbps DDOS hits the server. It depends on the capacity of server to deal with this amount of traffic. If the server capacity is low (Bandwidth wise and processing power wise) The server will be unable to perform the services and websites will be down. After the 500mbps DDOS stops, the server will start functioning again normally. Yes the servers will be functioning again in matter of Seconds. As soon as they process the junk requests completely.

Comment: I know it will function normally, but in how long? Like say it starts up again in a second, will it still be junked up?

Comment: Yes the servers will be functioning again in matter of Seconds. As soon as they process the junk requests completely.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic ddos attack scenario. i think they call this a reflection attack.

You forge billions of request, with the requester being the ip address(es) of the website you wish to attack. if you can send them with enough frequency, this results in a DDOS caused by the website you are attacking receiving all of the response headers from your malicious requests. You can supplement this attack by a simple botnet ddos targeting ajax resources and post/put requests. the latter method is especially useful against PHP, which populates `$_FILES` and `$_POST` whether your script uses them or not. A basic way to thwart this is to define for each route which request methods are allowed, and kill the script if a disallowed request method is present. This only works against a garden variety of script kiddies, because the pro's will be able to cause an overflow before the request even reaches the php daemon.